# PHP read from database and create csv files from table

Tags: php, database, csv, echo

I have a database with one table inside it.

The table has columns: Animal, Name, and Age. And the information inside the table are:

Animal | Name | Age

Dog | Amy | 2

Dog | Bert | 1

Dog | Charlie | 6

Cat | Don | 2

Cat | Ellie | 7

Fish | Frank | 1

I'd like to convert this table into 3 separate csv files through php. So one file echoed will be named Dog, the other Cat, and the last will be Fish, all with their data included through a link.

I was able to get a PHP file to to read all the tables in one database, but it seems inefficient for me to keep creating new tables when I can have all the data put into one table. Just can't figure out how to separate them by Animals.

```
if($result !== false) { // if at least one table in database
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<br />'. $row['Tables_in_abc1'];
        header('Content-type: text/csv');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=file1.csv'); 
        $stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w'); 
        fputcsv($stdout, $row);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Stackover Flow is not a free code service. We can help you with coding problems, if you've shown that you've already attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @ChickenFeet hey man, sorry, I didn't know. I just added my code

Comment: note your script can only output 1 file at the time. You could store 3 csv files on the server. But sent to the browser can only be one at the time

Comment: @IvoP Thanks for the heads up. I'll look into how to fix that after I figure this one out, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a where cause in your sql， like this:

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE where Animal = "Dog"
```

The `$result` would be only Dogs.

Comment: If I have a growing list of animals, is there a way for me to create a csv for all the animals instead of doing it manually? And not have them repeat (since I have multiple Dogs, Cats, Fish, etc)

Comment: you can  encapsulation that script into an function, with a parameter named $Animal. then run a SELECT distinct( Animal) from YOUR_TABLE  query to get a list of all the different Animals. then call that function for each Animals in the list.

Comment: I would add a table called Animal, having at least two columns: id and animal

in the one table you already have, you then use 1 for dog, 2 for cat etc.
that way you can easily find all possible type of animals from the newly created table.
And you would avoid typo's like "Dog", "dog" etc